# sharing information among objects

Tags: java

To share TaskKey among Tasks, which one is better? Are there other better way?

way1 share by a key object.In this way, The client code(Task Queue) is easier to write to config the task table. But every task has to waste memory to store the TaskKey object.

```
class TaskKey {
    int key1;
    int key2;
    // key3...
    TaskKey(int key1, int key2) {
        this.key1 = key1;
        this.key2 = key2;
    }
}

abstract class Task implements Cloneable {
    TaskKey key;
    int taskData;
    Task(TaskKey key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
    int getKey1() {
        return key.key1;
    }
    int getKey2() {
        return key.key2;
    }
    Task newInstance(int taskData) {
        Task task = (Task) clone();
        task.taskData = taskData;
        return task;
    }
    abstract void doSomething();
}

class TaskQueue {
    Task[][] taskTable;
    void addTask(Task task) {
        taskTable[task.getKey1()][task.getKey2()] = task;
    }
    void config() {
        addTask(new Task(new TaskKey(1, 1)) {
            void doSomething() {}
        });
        addTask(new Task(new TaskKey(1, 2)) {
            void doSomething() {}
        });
        addTask(new Task(new TaskKey(2, 1)) {
            void doSomething() {}
        });
    }

    Queue<Task> queue;
    void put(int key1, int key2, int taskData) {
        Task task = taskTable[key1][key2];
        queue.add(task.newInstance(taskData));
    }
}
```

way2 share by the task class.In this way, The client code(Task Queue) is troublesomely to write to config the task table(to override the getKey() method of Task). But every task do not need to waste memory to store the TaskKey object, because the key information are shared by the concrete Task class.

```
abstract class Task implements Cloneable {
    int taskData;
    abstract int getKey1();
    abstract int getKey2();
    abstract void doSomething();
    Task newInstance(int taskData) {
        Task task = (Task) clone();
        task.taskData = taskData;
        return task;
    }
}

class TaskQueue {
    Task[][] taskTable;
    void addTask(Task task) {
        taskTable[task.getKey1()][task.getKey2()] = task;
    }
    void config() {
        addTask(new Task() {
            int getKey1() { return 1; }
            int getKey2() { return 1; }
            void doSomething() {}
        });
        addTask(new Task() {
            int getKey1() { return 1; }
            int getKey2() { return 2; }
            void doSomething() {}
        });
        addTask(new Task() {
            int getKey1() { return 2; }
            int getKey2() { return 1; }
            void doSomething() {}
        });
    }

    Queue<Task> queue;
    void put(int key1, int key2, int taskData) {
        Task task = taskTable[key1][key2];
        queue.add(task.newInstance(taskData));
    }
}
```

another way1 and way2

```
interface TaskExecutor {
    void exec(Task task);
}

class TaskKey {
    int key1;
    int key2;
    int key3;
    TaskExecutor executor;
}

class Task /*another way1*/ {
    TaskKey key;
    int taskData;// in fact it is not only a int

    int getKey1() { // because i need to retrieve key1 from a task
        return key.key1;
    }
    // also get methods for key2 key3

    void exec(){
        key.executor.exec(this);
    }
}

class Task /*another way2*/ {
    public final int key1;
    public final int key2;
    public final int key3;
    private final TaskExecutor executor;
    int taskData;

    void exec(){
        executor.exec(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't want to do it the second way. For something as simple as storing two `int`s, reflection seems to be a bit overkill. The amount of memory performance you get from this is very small, and jvm will have to work that much harder to figure out your method overloading. It'll end up taking up a lot more code space (where do you think the java compiler stores all this extra information?) as well as slowing down execution.

The first way is one way of doing it, but if it's something as simple as storing two `int`s you might consider just having the two keys in your `Task` class instead of having a separate key.

```
abstract class Task implements Cloneable {
    int taskData;
    int key1;
    int key2;
    Task(int key1_, int key2_) {
        this.key1 = key1_;
        this.key2 = key2_;
    }
    int getKey1() {
        return key1;
    }
    int getKey2() {
        return key2;
    }
    Task newInstance(int taskData) {
        Task task = (Task) clone();
    task.taskData = taskData;
        return task;
    }
    abstract void doSomething();
}
```

However, it seems like you don't need to do this considering you already have a `Task[][]` storing all this data, unless if you need to get the values of `key1` and `key2` from a specific `Task` object, you can instead just directly do

```
void addTask(Task task, int i, int j) {
    taskTable[i][j] = task;
}
void config() {
    addTask(new Task(), 1, 1);
}
```

However, if you DO need to get the values of `key1` and `key2` from a specific `Task` object, you can instead use a `HashMap<TaskKey,Task>` instead of a `Task[][]` to store your data. That way you can

```
HashMap<TaskKey,Task> taskTable;
void addTask(Task task, int i, int j) {
    taskTable.put(new TaskKey(i,j), task);
}
Task getTask(int i, int j){
    return taskTable.get(new TaskKey(i,j));
}
void config() {
    addTask(new Task(), 1, 1);
}
```

though you'd probably need to generate a `hashCode()` and `equals()` method using your favorite IDE for both of them. This ends up being very memory efficient, with the same constant time access you have from the array.

Comment: I need to use key1, key2, key3 inside Task, and the doSomething() method will be replaced with a interface, and also the interface is another information need to be share among instances of a same specific Task class. Task will be create for many many times, so i want to save memory. and another question is: i'm using multi-threading, if i use hashmap as the task table, i may need to use ConcurrentHashMap. is really use hash map to retrieve task can be as   fast as array?

Comment: Here's the thing, if you just need 2 integers, that comes out to exactly 8 bytes per object. The alternative way of storing pointers to another TaskKey object you have stored somewhere else comes out to 8 bytes in a 64 bit system, so you're not really getting a win that way. 8 bytes/object in the grand scheme of things is not as significant as you might think. HashMaps have amortized O(1) access time, which means for all intents and purposes, retrieval is as fast as an array.

Comment: Also, if you are using an array for your data structure and you are multithreading then you have to be very, very careful. If you would need ConcurrentHashMap<Task> then Task[][] would not work.

Comment: i like way1, but for saving memory, i consider using way2. however, your answer bring me back to way1. thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Way2 actually takes up more memory. You are just moving the memory usage somewhere else. If you have 3000 different key1, key2 pairs, then it physically stores the 3000 different methods you wrote and puts it in somewhere in the code region of your memory, which takes up much more memory space than storing 2 ints per object

Comment: i have ask questions about another way1 and way2, could you please help me to choose a better one. and another fact need to be consider is that, i may has only  at most 1000 key1,key2,key3 group, it will be init at the beginning of main thread, but millions of tasks maybe created later for queuing tasks.

Comment: Keep a static TaskKey[][] somewhere, so instead of doing new TaskKey(3,2) millions of times, you can just taskKeyTable[3][2]

Comment: any suggestion about another way1 ans way2? i have edited my question, because i cannot paste code here.

Comment: Way1 seems to be the way to go.